# get all data in a mongo collection into a text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a Mongo collection in this syntax. How do I export each file into a text file including the arrays?

```
{
      _id: 1,
      "author": [
        {
          "fname": "Petr",
          "lname": "Kocircurka"
        }
      ],
      "title": "On topological dynamics of Turing machines",
      "journal": "Theor. Comput. Sci.",
      "volume": "174",
      "pages": [
        {
          "FirstNumber": "203",
          "LastNumber": "216"
        }
      ],
      "year": "1997",
      "url": "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/03043975/"
    }{
      _id: 2,
      "author": [
        {
          "fname": "Aviezri",
          "lname": "Fraenkel"
        },
        {
          "fname": "Jamie",
          "lname": "Simpson"
        }
      ],
      "title": "The exact number of squares in Fibonacci words",
      "journal": "Theor. Comput. Sci.",
      "volume": "218",
      "pages": [
        {
          "FirstNumber": "95",
          "LastNumber": "106"
        }
      ],
      "year": "1999",
      "url": "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/03043975/"
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `mongoexport` utility? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ I know it works for CSV and JSON. Not sure it solves your specific needs.

Comment: Yes, i have it does not export the array, also tried putting ./mongoexport

Comment: can you post the command that you used in exporting the collection and its output?

Comment: i need help with the command, i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoexport --db yourDbName --collection collectionName --out fileName.json -u userName -p yourPassword
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Comment: it has to be in a text file and the mongo collection contains array, it is supposed to be exported into the text file as fields.

Comment: Here replace yourDbName -> to your own  database name    filename.json->replace with location of your file in which you want to export and if you have credential for your database then use your credential on the places of userName and yourPassword otherwise don't include these credential.simply use     mongoexport --db yourDbName --collection collectionName --out fileName.json

Answer (score 0):

If your database is created without using username and password, you can use the following command which will give you json files for each of the collections that you have defined

```html
mongoexport --db databaseName --collection CollectionName --out fileName.json
```